# Null Pointer exception - DialogFragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialogfragment that is created when the user clicks a row in a xml table I have created. I want the dialogfragment to show the information that is shown in the row they selected. I get a null pointer exception when trying to reference the data in this way.

Here is my dialogfragment code:

```
public class EditDataDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnEditorActionListener {

public interface EditNameDialogListener {
    void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText);
}

private static final int MY_CODE = 12345;

private EditText mEditTextData;
private EditText mEditTextAlias;
private TextView mTextViewId;
private TextView mTextViewAlias;
private TextView mTextViewTime;
private TextView mTextViewData;
public static DatabaseFragment dbFrag = new DatabaseFragment();

public EditDataDialog() {
    // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_data, container);
    System.out.println("time: " + dbFrag.temp_time.getText());
    //DatabaseHandler cattleDb = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    //Cattle cattle = cattleDb.getCattle(dbFrag.temp);

    mEditTextAlias = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_alias);
    mEditTextData = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_data);

    mTextViewId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tag_id);
    mTextViewAlias = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tag_alias);
    mTextViewTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tag_time);
    mTextViewData =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tag_data);

    //System.out.println(dbFrag.temp_time.getText());

    mTextViewId.setText("Tag ID: test");
    mTextViewAlias.setText("Tag Alias: test");
    //mTextViewTime.setText("Tag Time Stamp: " + dbFrag.temp_time.getText());//dbFrag.time is NULL
    mTextViewData .setText("Tag Data: test\n");

    getDialog().setTitle("Enter your data");

    // Show soft keyboard automatically
    mEditTextData.requestFocus();
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mEditTextData.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    mEditTextAlias.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId) {
        // Return input text to activity

        EditDataDialogListener fragment = (EditDataDialogListener) getTargetFragment();//.onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), MY_CODE, data);
        //System.out.println(fragment);
        fragment.onFinishEditDialog(mEditTextAlias.getText().toString() +","+ mEditTextData.getText().toString());
        this.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is my DatabaseFragment, where the dialogfragment is created onClicks:

```
public class DatabaseFragment extends Fragment implements EditDataDialogListener {

protected static final int MY_CODE = 12345;

public DatabaseFragment() {
    // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}

/*The number of tags that have been
read and waiting to be placed into the database*/
int tags_found=4;                    

Date dateNow = new Date();

//Temporary values used when user clicks a row in the database
int temp;
int row_i = 1;
TextView temp_row;                  
TextView temp_id;
TextView temp_alias;
TextView temp_time;
TextView temp_data;

//Buttons in the database
Button transferDb, restoreDb;           

//Class for exporting database to .csv files
ExportDatabase exportDb;
String exportFileName = "CattleManagerDb.csv";


String id = "e9-23-f3-e2-01-11";
String alias = "Doug";
String time;
String data = "data";



public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_database, container, false);
            transferDb = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bSQLTransfer);
            restoreDb = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bSQLRestore);

            final DatabaseHandler cattleDb = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());//does this need final?
            TableLayout tl1 = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cattleDb); 
            while(tags_found>0){
                View newRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_layout, null,false);
                tl1.addView(newRow);

                TextView row = (TextView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.row);
                TextView tag_id = (TextView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.tag_id);
                TextView tag_alias = (TextView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.tag_alias);
                TextView tag_time = (TextView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.tag_time);
                TextView tag_data = (TextView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.tag_data);
                Cattle newCattle = new Cattle();

                SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss a zzz");
                time = ft.format(dateNow);

                newCattle.setTagID(id);
                newCattle.setAlias(alias);
                newCattle.setTimeStamp(time);
                newCattle.setTagData(data);

                row.setText(Integer.toString(row_i));
                tag_id.setText(id);
                tag_alias.setText(alias);
                tag_time.setText(time);
                tag_data.setText(data);

                cattleDb.addCattle(newCattle);

                //When a user clicks a row in the database
                newRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Saving temporary tag TextViews for the clicked row
                        temp_row = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row);
                        temp_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tag_id);
                        temp_alias = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tag_alias);
                        temp_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tag_time);
                        temp_data = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tag_data);
                        temp = Integer.parseInt(temp_row.getText().toString());
                        showEditDialog();
                        }
                });
                tags_found--;
                row_i++;
            }
            cattleDb.close();
            /*
            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all cattle...");
            List<Cattle> cattle = cattleDb.getAllCattle();
            for(Cattle cn : cattle) {
                String log = "ID: " + cn.getID()+ " , Tag ID: " + cn.getTagID() + " , Alias: " + cn.getAlias() + " Time: " + cn.getTimeStamp() + " Data: " + cn.getTagData();
                Log.d("Name: ", log);
            }
            */


    transferDb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {//Do we want to keep adding to the database infinitely?
            //---------------------------------
            //Create and transfer the .csv file
            //---------------------------------
            exportDb = new ExportDatabase(getActivity());
            exportDb.exportDataToCSV(exportFileName);          

            //new AsyncEmail().addAttachment(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + exportFileName);
            new AsyncEmail().execute();

            //------------------
            //Clear the database
            //------------------
            int cattle_i=1;
            TableLayout tl1 = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cattleDb);          
            View rowHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_header, null, false);
            tl1.removeAllViews();
            tl1.addView(rowHeader);//change newRow to headerRow
            int numCattle = cattleDb.getCattleCount(); 
            while(cattle_i<=numCattle){
                Cattle cattle = cattleDb.getCattle(cattle_i);
                cattleDb.deleteCattle(cattle);
                cattle_i++;
            }
            /*
            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all cattle...");
            List<Cattle> cattle = cattleDb.getAllCattle();
            for(Cattle cn : cattle) {
                String log = "ID: " + cn.getID()+ " , Tag ID: " + cn.getTagID() + " , Alias: " + cn.getAlias() + " Time: " + cn.getTimeStamp() + " Data: " + cn.getTagData();
                Log.d("Name: ", log);
            }
            */
            }

    });

    return rootView;
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

private void showEditDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    EditDataDialog editDataDialog = new EditDataDialog();
    editDataDialog.show(fm.beginTransaction(), "fragment_edit_data");
    editDataDialog.setTargetFragment(this, MY_CODE);
}


@Override
public void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText) {
    DatabaseHandler cattleDb = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    Cattle cattle = cattleDb.getCattle(temp);
    int commaOffset = inputText.indexOf(",");
    String inputAlias = inputText.substring(0,commaOffset).trim();
    String inputData = inputText.substring(commaOffset+1).trim();

    System.out.println(inputAlias);
    System.out.println(inputData);

    if(inputAlias.length()!=0) {//Only update if field was modified
        cattle.setAlias(inputAlias);
        temp_alias.setText(inputAlias);
        cattleDb.updateCattle(cattle);
    }
    if(inputData.length()!=0) {//Only update if field was modified
        cattle.setTagData(inputData);
        temp_data.setText(inputData);
        cattleDb.updateCattle(cattle);
    }

    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all cattle...");
    List<Cattle> cattleList = cattleDb.getAllCattle();
    for(Cattle cn : cattleList) {
        String log = "ID: " + cn.getID()+ " , Tag ID: " + cn.getTagID() + " , Alias: " + cn.getAlias() + " Time: " + cn.getTimeStamp() + " Data: " + cn.getTagData();
        Log.d("Name: ", log);
    }
} 

}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
12-02 22:08:00.932: I/Process(31818): Sending signal. PID: 31818 SIG: 9
12-02 22:10:52.880: D/AbsListView(605): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-02 22:10:52.890: D/AbsListView(605): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
12-02 22:10:52.890: D/AbsListView(605): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-02 22:10:52.900: D/AbsListView(605): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
12-02 22:10:52.900: D/AbsListView(605): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-02 22:10:52.900: D/AbsListView(605): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-02 22:10:52.910: I/endeffect(605): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=0, getHeight()=0, this=android.widget.ListView{42ab9898 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0002 app:id/left_drawer}
12-02 22:10:52.920: D/libEGL(605): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
12-02 22:10:52.920: D/libEGL(605): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
12-02 22:10:52.930: D/libEGL(605): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
12-02 22:10:52.930: I/Adreno200-EGL(605): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3579225)
12-02 22:10:52.930: I/Adreno200-EGL(605): Build Date: 04/22/13 Mon
12-02 22:10:52.930: I/Adreno200-EGL(605): Local Branch: adreno_sba_20130419
12-02 22:10:52.930: I/Adreno200-EGL(605): Remote Branch: 
12-02 22:10:52.930: I/Adreno200-EGL(605): Local Patches: 
12-02 22:10:52.930: I/Adreno200-EGL(605): Reconstruct Branch: 
12-02 22:10:52.990: D/OpenGLRenderer(605): Enabling debug mode 0
12-02 22:10:53.020: D/AbsListView(605): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-02 22:10:53.020: I/endeffect(605): AbsListView.onLayout(), getWidth()=720, getHeight()=1701, this=android.widget.ListView{42ab9898 VFED.VC. ......ID -720,0-0,1701 #7f0b0002 app:id/left_drawer}
12-02 22:10:53.020: D/AbsListView(605): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
12-02 22:10:53.020: D/AbsListView(605): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-02 22:10:53.170: D/AbsListView(605): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-02 22:10:53.180: I/endeffect(605): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=720, getHeight()=1701, this=android.widget.ListView{42ab9898 IFED.VC. ......ID -720,0-0,1701 #7f0b0002 app:id/left_drawer}
12-02 22:10:53.190: D/AbsListView(605): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-02 22:10:53.190: I/endeffect(605): AbsListView.onLayout(), getWidth()=720, getHeight()=1701, this=android.widget.ListView{42ab9898 IFED.VC. ......ID -720,0-0,1701 #7f0b0002 app:id/left_drawer}
12-02 22:11:04.932: D/GestureDetector(605): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
12-02 22:11:04.942: D/AbsListView(605): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
12-02 22:11:04.942: D/AbsListView(605): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-02 22:11:05.582: D/GestureDetector(605): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
12-02 22:11:05.673: I/endeffect(605): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=720, getHeight()=1701, this=android.widget.ListView{42ab9898 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-720,1701 #7f0b0002 app:id/left_drawer}
12-02 22:11:05.673: D/AbsListView(605): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-02 22:11:05.673: I/endeffect(605): AbsListView.onLayout(), getWidth()=720, getHeight()=1701, this=android.widget.ListView{42ab9898 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-720,1701 #7f0b0002 app:id/left_drawer}
12-02 22:11:06.053: D/AbsListView(605): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
12-02 22:11:06.053: D/AbsListView(605): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-02 22:11:06.613: D/GestureDetector(605): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
12-02 22:11:06.634: D/AndroidRuntime(605): Shutting down VM
12-02 22:11:06.634: W/dalvikvm(605): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41787ac8)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at com.rfidsensorsystems.cattletracker.EditDataDialog.onCreateView(EditDataDialog.java:41)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
12-02 22:11:06.634: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The error seems to be at line 41 , as mentioned in the logcat which means

is sending a NPE.

So please, check whether you have the corresponding id in your XML i.e in R.id....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that all your view ids are correct. The error message says the NullPointerException is line 41. Which looks like:

```
mTextViewAlias.setText("Tag Alias: test");
```

Make sure mTextViewAlias was actually set to a control. You'd be surprised how often the wrong id is being used.

Comment: I have verified that my XML id's are correct. I am getting the NullPointer when I try to reference the data like this: dbFrag.temp_time.getText(). Is this valid? Eclipse does not give me an error but perhaps I cannot reference my temp_time TextView in this way in my dialogfragment.

Comment: Ok now I understand why I get a null pointer. I am creating a new DatabaseFragment, but I want to refer to the DatabaseFragment that CALLED my dialogfragment. Any ideas on how I should do this?

Comment: @Doug : A Fragment shouldn't communicate with another Fragment unless one is a child Fragment of the other. Normally Fragments should be created by (and managed by) an Activity and all communication between Fragments should be done via the Activity using callbacks and public methods in the Fragments that the Activity can access.

Comment: @Squonk Unless I am mistaken, my DialogFragment should be a child of my EditDataDialog fragment. I call the creation of the DialogFragment with an onClick method inside of the EditDataDialog fragment. This makes it its child, correct?

Comment: Squonk is absolutely on mark here. The Fragment is like a View. View's should not know who their parents or siblings are. If you are unfamiliar with this concept, look up the Observer pattern (it is a part of the Gang of Four software design patterns).

Comment: @Doug : Technically a 'child' Fragment would be one embedded within another Fragment's view space at which point you would use `getChildFragmentManager()`. Anything with a Dialog style is neither one thing or another and could be considered a 'child' of the Activity. Ideally your `showEditDialog()` method should make a callback to the Activity to tell it to create the `DialogFragment`. When the `DialogFragment` is done it should return data to the Activity which in turn will pass the data to the database Fragment. It sounds convoluted but it's part of the modular design approach for Fragments.